# Input string was not in a correct format. Format Exception was Unhandled

Tags: c#

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGryQ.jpg

```
   int ctr, len;
    string gee;
    t = kalliskaBillingDataSet.Tables["DealerDetail"];
    len = t.Rows.Count - 1;     
      r = t.Rows[len];
     string id = r["DealerID"].ToString();
     gee = id.Substring(1, 3);
      ctr = int.Parse(gee);
```

Input string was not in a correct format in the line::

```
ctr = int.Parse(gee);
```

Comment: What's the value of "code" after "id.SubString(1,3)"? Did you try to debug it? The exception is thrown because your string "code" cannot be parsed to an int (it may contain letters, weird characters, it's a float, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

`E00` is not a valid decimal string. You need to parse it as though it's a hex string.

Use something like:

```
int.Parse(code, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Of course, it's possible that the value is not supposed to be hexadecimal, in which case you have an error.

To more gracefully recover from such situations, use `int.TryParse(code, out value)` instead, and check the return value for true/false, indicating success/failure.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the screenshot, `code` was `E00`, which cannot be converted to an integer.